# В трактовке пары болезный - болезненный источники разошлись; чему верить (см.)?

Tags: значение-слов, паронимы

С "болезненным" всё ясно; слово простое, немудрящее.

А с "болезным" непонятки, не складывается у меня с ним...

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

> **БОЛЕЗНЫЙ**, -ого; ***м.*** *(обычно в обращении). Нар.-разг.* Милый, любезный, дорогой. *Что пригорюнился, б.?* **<Болезная**, -ой;
>   ***ж.*** *Не плачь, моя б.*
>
> ---

("Красиво плывут! — Кто? — Вон та группа в полосатых купальниках". - Это я про словарную бэ с точкой: клёво смотрится.)

---

**[болезный](https://paronymonline.ru/%D0%91/197)**

> — *(устар. и прост.)*. Вызывающий сострадание, жалость.
>
> Примеры:
>
> болезный друг;
>
> болезная душа;
>
> болезное создание.
>
> Сравните паронимы: болезненный юноша — юноша, подверженный заболеваниям;
>   болезный юноша — юноша, вызывающий сострадание, жалость.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А я своею рукою написала:

> Имярек сердешный, спасибо на добром слове! И так неожиданно: я бессонная, плохонькая - и вдруг так по головушке хворой погладили...

"Болезную", помучившись изрядно, заменила на "хворую".

Но ничего так и не поняла. Льзя ль? нельзя ль?

Про бессонную / дурную / галлюцинирующую голову сказать - болезная? Она же мне дорога, а местами и мила, а?

Но возник ещё и Ушаков с жалостливостью и состраданьем, О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по определениям словарей, эпитет **болезный** употребляется по отношению к личности. Вот и у Ефремовой то же самое:

> болезный — м. разг. сниж. Тот, кто вызывает сострадание, жалость.
>   Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000 …

**Тот, кто** вызывает сострадание, а **не то, что** вызывает сострадание.

А головушка - *бедная, горемычная, жалкая, несчастная, многострадальная* и т.д.
И "хворая" не всегда точно передаёт мысль автора, если у него  не **больная** имеется в виду, а **вызывающая сострадание**, больше подойдёт **бедная** или **исстрадавшаяся**. Впрочем, текст нам незнаком, может, там именно с болезнью связано, а не с переживаниями, тогда **хворая** будет на месте.

Answer (score 1):

Любить — значит жалеть. В русском языке эти слова долгое время были синонимами. Любили интеллигенты, а народ любимых жалел. https://culture.wikireading.ru/20923

Поэтому любезный — это и вызывающий жалость, и одновременно милый, любимый. Мы же сейчас говорим "бедненький мой", то есть любим и жалеем.

И про хворую головушку можно сказать: по головушке болезной погладили...

**«Болезный!»** ― подумал Теркин крестьянским словом, каким, бывало, его приемная мать жалела его, когда он, мальчиком, заболевал. [П. Д. Боборыкин. Василий Теркин (1892)

Что ж я наделала? Очнись, **болезный мой**! Синегла-азенький! [Б. А. Лавренев. Сорок первый (1924)]

Да милый ты мой, **болезный**, ― сказала она вдруг в приступе нежности и принялась осыпать его поцелуями. [Чингиз Айтматов. Белый пароход (1970)]

Comment: Шарончик, ещё немножко аргументов за, плиииз! Примеров чужих не надо - они же мне противоречат! По Ушакову - головушка ***моя*** жалкая, вызывающая ***моё к ней*** сострадание - болезная?

Comment: "Любовь" не равно "жалость".  Любовь ближе к тяготению.Про болезного копайте в сторону болельщика.

Comment: Про голову сказать (болезная) нельзя: Болезновати = иметь большое о ком (!) попечение, обильную любовь.

Comment: Мне кажется.что в наше время слово "болезный" употребляется редко, по крайней мере в наше регионе я его вообще не слышу. Слово народное, а традиции народные порастерялись. Но его заменило слово "бедный". Мой бедный, мой бедненький, мой хороший - это о любимых, а бедный, бедняга - нейтральное сочувствие. И употребляется это слово весьма свободно, можно и себя. любимого, пожалеть: устали мои ножки, бедные, болезные, и головушка моя бедная, хворая, болезная. Что касается Ушакова,  то второе значение слова "болезный" из его словаря обычно выглядит как болезный к людям, если судить по Нацкорпусу.

Comment: "Болезный" ближе к "сердобольный".

Comment: В Нацкорпусе  это значение слова "болезный" встречается значительно реже. Там  этим словом обычно выражается жалость и любовь, а иногда оно  приобретает противоположный (иронический) смысл: сейчас мы с тобой разберемся, болезный ты мой.